# MongoDB performance with geo data

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geo, query-performance

I am using a single MongoDB 3.0.1 instance (without sharded cluster, replicas, etc) with one database containing a collection with 15324247 points. Of course, points are indexed with a 2dsphere index. Queries are done through a Node.js app.

Looking for points near a concrete lon&lat, it requires 11710ms to return 59925 points.
The same query including a restricted project (only geometry), it still requires 4351ms to return 59925 points.

```
find({
    "geometry": {
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [110.30838012695312,
                -20.86522808076763]
            },
            "$maxDistance": 1000
        }
    }
},
{
    geometry: 1
})
```

Changing the query and using and aggregation instead of find it requires: 5799ms but returns 8882 points, and projecting only the geometry 4606ms returns 8882 points.

```
aggregate([{
    "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [110.30838012695312,
            -20.86522808076763]
        },
        "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
        "maxDistance": 964,
        "spherical": true,
        "num": 70000
    }
}])
```

Although all the elements are indexed, is this a normal performance? How could be improved? I have tried $geoWithin instead of $geoNear, or adding more keys to geoindex, using cursor.get instead of cursor.on in Node.js side, increasing/decreasing batchSize for aggregation... but performances are quite similar in all cases.

And the second question is why the aggregation is returning less results than the find?

Comment: Could you please format your queries so it's not a fight to read them? Also, you are returning a lot of points, and a big part of the problem seems to be either reading from disk or piping it over the network, not the geo query. I don't think the performance is unreasonable - can't you have a more restrictive query, or limit the number of results?

Comment: No, I can't have any more restrictive query or less results. All are points that must be displayed in a map, and all of them are important.
So, the real problem is the big result number and reading from disc, not the geoquery?